# pagination with search but the search is not working

Tags: php

I have this code for `test3.php`, with pagination and search, the pagination is working fine but the search is not working. I don't know what is the problem in my code. Can somebody help me with my search function. I've searched the internet but I couldn't find any solution about my problem. Please help me about it. Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pagination</title>



<body>

<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="">

Search:<input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search the table" />

</form>

<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("region_survey") or die (mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM municipality ORDER BY id ASC");

$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql);  
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { 
$pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 
} else { 
$pn = 1;
} 

$itemsPerPage = 10; 

$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);

if ($pn < 1) {
$pn = 1;
}   else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
$pn = $lastPage; 
} 

$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
$centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}   else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    }

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM municipality ORDER BY id ASC $limit"); 

$paginationDisplay = ""; 

if ($lastPage != "1"){

$paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';

if ($pn != 1) {
    $previous = $pn - 1;
$paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '? pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
} 

$paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';

if ($pn != $lastPage) {
    $nextPage = $pn + 1;
$paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?  pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
} 
}

$outputList = '';

?>
<div id="tables">
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>LO Name</th>
        <th>Province</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Update</th>
    </tr>


<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    $id=$row['id'];
?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['province_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['municipality_name']; ?></td>
        <td><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox"
id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></td>
<td><a href="update.php<?php echo '?id='.$row['id']; ?>">Edit</a>     </td>

    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("region_survey", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM municipality");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


$total = $row[0];
echo "Total rows: " . $total;

mysql_close($con);
?>

<br />
<br />
<?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not add the keyword on which the query will search in your database use below query

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM municipality where <your-field-name> LIKE %".$_POST['<your input box name>']." ORDER BY id ASC");`

Hope this will help you in solving your problem

Comment: whre should i put that code?

Comment: in your sql query use the where LIKE clause in your sql query

Comment: i know that but i'm just a beginner in php and i hope you understand me..idont know know where exactly to put it..can you please show me..

Comment: You can add it in you `$sql` as well as in your `$sql2` which contains the sql query

Comment: i trid it but theres an error --Notice: Undefined index: search_box in D:\wamp\www\TestingSite\test3.php on line 139

Comment: show me what you have modified your query

Comment: i add this to my $sql$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM municipality WHERE province_id ORDER BY id ASC");

Comment: and this is for the $sql2  if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM municipality WHERE province_id LIKE %".$_POST['search_box']." ORDER BY id ASC $limit"); 
}

Comment: `$sql2 if(isset($_POST['search'])){ $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM municipality WHERE province_id LIKE %".$_POST['search_box']."% ORDER BY id ASC $limit"); } `  use this

Comment: I TRIED YOUR CODE BUT NOW I HAVE THIS ERROR    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in D:\wamp\www\TestingSite\test3.php on line 178

Comment: pass the query in `mysql_fetch_array($sql)`

Comment: error is throwing because you are not using the sql function properly

Comment: The current error defines that you are not passing any parameter while fecting the data

Comment: i tried what you said and theres no error but now the proble is the pagination is not working it showing all my records in my the table and the search is not working..